# How to adjust a date format in an array?

Tags: php, arrays, date, format

Here, I want to get only date from an array.
Array is:

```
print_r($incomplete);
Output:
Array
(
    [0] => 2015-09-21 11:20:37
)
```

And **I want in below Format**,

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2015-09-21
)
```

I have tried like this,

```
echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime($incomplete));
```

Answer (score 5):

The date conversion code works. What you have in `$incomplete` is an array, so you will have to use `$incomplete[0]` to access that value. Easy solution for that would be this:

```
$incomplete[0] = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($incomplete[0]));
```

Now you have the same array data without the time.

Answer (score 2):

`strtotime` takes input as STRING.

```
echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime($incomplete[0]));
```

Answer (score 2):

`strtotime` expects to be given a string containing an English date format and will try to parse that format into a Unix timestamp. And you have passed `array` to this function. Also add array index as below :

```
echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime($incomplete[0]));
```

Answer (score 2):

The date conversion will not work with the array directly. So you need to pass the array element in place of array in your code :

```
echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime($incomplete[0]));
```

Hope this will help, please let me know if you need any help further.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to target the cell of your array which contain the date like below :

```
echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime($incomplete[0]));
```

Comment: Thank you all, but I want in array format as I mentioned in my question.
Here, I am getting only date that I want but in array format.

Answer (score 1):

Your conversion from `Y-m-d H:i:s` or `datetime` to `date` is fine. However you can't just execute that code on your array. You need to grab the specific array key-value pair.

#### Example

```
// Creating your array
$array = array(
    '0' => '2015-09-20 10:20:30'
);

// Get date from array and create DateTime Object
$date = new DateTime($array[0]);

// Change date format and output
$array[0] = $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

#### On arrays

> An array is a data structure that stores one or more similar type of values in a single value. For example if you want to store 100 numbers then instead of defining 100 variables its easy to define an array of 100 length.
>
> There are three different kind of arrays and each array value is accessed using an ID c which is called array index. [...]

Resources:

- [Tutorial on arrays](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_arrays.htm)
- [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)